# How to count number of rows based on a certain value in a panel data set?

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-handling

I am handling a panel data like df. So I have a unique UserID (Uid), a TimeVariable (TV) and  my main variable of interest(MV, dummy coded).
Each row represents a unique UiD TV combination.
Now I want to create a new variable (NV), which counts basically the number of events (MV=1) that happend up to time TV.

The contect: I want to have a count variable (NV) that basically counts for each moment in time how often Event MV=1 happend up to that moment (TV).

So far I can only manage to sum it up per UserId but not having it on a increasing level.

## What I managed so far:

`df <-  df %>% group_by(user_id) %>% mutate(NV=count_if(1,MV))`

The result is given to my on a aggreate basis per user ID for the MV

So the df looks like:

```
UI TV MV
1  1  0
1  2  1
1  3  0
2  1  0
2  2  0
2  3  1
2  4  2
3  1  1
3  2  0
3  3  1
3  4  1
```

The resuls with my code so far is:

```
UI TV MV NV
1  1  0  1
1  2  1  1
1  3  0  1
2  1  0  2
2  2  0  2
2  3  1  2
2  4  2  2
3  1  1  3
3  2  0  3
3  3  1  3
3  4  1  3
```

What I actually want:

```
UI TV MV NV
1  1  0  0
1  2  1  1
1  3  0  1
2  1  0  0
2  2  0  0
2  3  1  1
2  4  2  2
3  1  1  1
3  2  0  1
3  3  1  2
3  4  1  3
```

Thanks very much in advance for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could `group_by` `UI` and take cumulative sum of occurrence of `MV == 1`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(UI) %>%
  mutate(NV = cumsum(MV == 1))


#      UI    TV    MV    NV
#   <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     1     0     0
# 2     1     2     1     1
# 3     1     3     0     1
# 4     2     1     0     0
# 5     2     2     0     0
# 6     2     3     1     1
# 7     2     4     2     1
# 8     3     1     1     1
# 9     3     2     0     1
#10     3     3     1     2
#11     3     4     1     3
```

---

In base R, we can use `ave`

```
with(df, ave(MV == 1, UI, FUN = cumsum))
#[1] 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 3
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(UI = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), TV = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), MV = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```